# Classic ADO.NET or Entity Framework better for larger scale database transactions?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, ado.net

We just started on a project to develop a web portal using .NET 3.5 and MSSQL 2008. A question was raised on which is the sensible choice to handle data access which involves tens of thousands of records up to hundreds of thousands? I saw a table somewhere that compared ADO.NET, EF and LINQ to SQL and it seemed like LINQ to SQL is the slowest by average but ADO.NET choked on large operations.

By the way, what are your thoughts on using NHibernate on a large scale?

Answer (score 3):

Everything is going to use ADO.NET when it boils down to it.

I would probably write a Proof of Concept app using the Repository pattern (with one repository using Entity Framework and the other using raw ADO.NET).

Run some tests and see which method suits your needs better.

I will tell you that using vanilla ADO.NET will give you finer grain control over what is actually being executed against your database.

Answer (score 0):

Both Linq2Sql and EF translate your source code into T-Sql in case with MS SQL. The speed varies based on how they translate to the sql. Remeber, you can always call your own sql (s-procs) using either one, thus having more control over whats being executed against your store for the cases when the generated sql is not performing well enough.

Answer (score 0):

*StackOverflow.com* uses `LINQ-to-SQL`. I'd guess they're working with hundred of thousands of records by now. Is SO's performance acceptable to your team?

And as others have said. It ends up being the same thing anyways, `T-SQL`. ORMs are about Functional programming and software design. Optimizations of the underlying queries can always be made. Using vanilla `ADO.NET` just because someone's test showed it to perform better in that specific circumstance seems like a bad reason to me.

[`LINQPad`](http://www.linqpad.net/) is a very useful tool for comparing frameworks and optimizing queries. If you haven't already, you should check it out.

Comment: I came from an Oracle background so I pretty much got no clues about LINQ2SQL and ADO.NET seemed most comfortable for me so far but the worry lies in the possibility of switching to another method when our website is already mature, which is why I had to ask around. Thanks for the link!

Comment: @fred: Ah, got ya. If you are just getting into it now, I think Entity Framework 4 is the way to go. Microsoft has made their commitment to the technology pretty clear. And they've shown it with all the improvements in v4. Working with a ORM versus straight queries will take some getting used to. But I expect you'll love it once it all starts coming together. LINQPad really speeds up the learning process and lets you easily test your Entities while they're still being developed. Best of luck with the project.